# Is there another solution for SQL with many columns

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Good morning everyone,

I have a master table with material data (which will be later compared with another table), but on every material, we are measuring like **30** values and each of them has - **Minimal value, Maximal Value, Nominal Value, Tool and Image**.

[image]

So I was forced to make a table with over **150** columns
Is there another way of avoiding to have this much columns? (except making 30 tables)

Thank you very much and have a nice day,

Petr

Comment: perhaps you can use a `json` data type?

Comment: Oh thank you, ill try that. :) I'm kinda new in this.

Comment: 30 values to 150 columns looks like there are a lot of columns which are not used for every item - perhaps you could group the most common into 1 table and the less common into another (etc)

Comment: Most of the time, every item needs every column. Ill take a look on the JSON data type, it Will probably do the thing :)

Comment: If this is a (fairly) finite list, without much redundancy, then this might in fact be the most optimal design.

Answer (score 1):

You can 
Create a new Table **Material** and include columns:-

- Id (auto-increment and primary key)
- Material Name

Create another table **MeasurementInfo** and include columns:-

- Id (auto-increment & primary key)
- Measurment Value(eg:- Length)
- Minimal Value
- Maximal Value
- Nominal Value
- Tool
- Image
- MaterialId (foreing key references from Material table Id column)

Comment: With this model, image would belong in the other table.